# Apache2 - WSGI file not found Issue

Tags: apache2, wsgi

I run bash script file through python code. The script is located /home/myscript.sh. The script convert html to pdf and print. If I run the python program in development mode it works fine but if I run in WSGI production mode it give me error "File not found" to print. But if I give access 7777 to home directory it works fine. And I need to do this access step every time whenever machine restarted. Also it not good solution.

I search a lot and change apache2.conf file

```
<Directory /home/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But still there is problem. Please help me. I used Apache 2.4.9 version. Advance thanks

**Update**

In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file
"User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}" and "Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}"

And in envvars it sets like

export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

Still problem exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If issue is with directory

Example /home

Move the file from /home to /var/www

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/filename
```

or

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/filename
```

If the issue with USB port

Example

> ttyUSB0

,

> ttyACM0

,

> ttyACM1

Write script to change the owner

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo chown www-data:www-data /dev/ttyACM0
```

Call this script from your code using subprocess.call

But allow the user www-data to run this file as sudo with out password

> sudo visudo

and add the below line in the last

```
www-data ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD : /var/www/filename
```

or

```
www-data ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD : ALL
```